# How to use different form with different controller functions and the same route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I'm building an app with Laravel

In the same `blade` file I have different **forms**. In a `div` I have **two forms**.

In one form the `user` writes something in a `textarea`. After press the button ok, the page is reloaded and the data stored in a table of database.

The other form appears in a **modal** and it contains other option that the `user` can set and after press another button the data should stored in another table of database.

So how I can do this? I tried to `route` the function in my controller in this way:

```
Route::post('/anam','AnamnController@store');
Route::post('/anam','AnamnController@storePar');
```

and the tag form:

```
<form action="{{ action('AnamController@store') }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<form id="formA" action="{{ action('AnamnesiController@storePar') }}" method="" class="form-horizontal">
```

But these return to me errors. So what I have to do?

Thanks!

Comment: what error you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's impossible to use the same route for two different functions unless you change one by get instead of post for example:

```
Route::post('/anam','AnamnController@store');
Route::get('/anam','AnamnController@storePar');
```

but you can make this logic:

```
Route::post('/anam','AnamnController@store');
```

and the tag form:

```
<form action="{{ action('AnamController@store') }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <input name="input_name" value="input-val" />
</form>
```

in controller:

```
public function store (){
   if(request()->input_name == 'val-1')
       this->store1();
   else
       this->store2();
}

protected function store1 () {
  //
}
protected function store2 () {
      //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two routes with the same **url** that has the same route **method**.

In your case you have two `POST` methods going to the same **url**. The second route definition is cancelling out the first.

Rename one of them.